# How can I use two sets of data on NVD3 on single click

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js, pie-chart

I am using `NVD3` Graph which was used on the template we have purchased.

I have two sets of data:

1. `testData` - used for the bar chart:

   [image: bar chart]
2. `pieChartData` - used for the pie chart:

   [image: pie chart]

The goal is when I clicked the POSITIONS on the PIE CHART Footer, the values on the Pie Chart and Bar Chart will change according to the assigned DATA above.

The DATA for the footer is now set to pieChartData that is why when I choose any positions on the FOOTER it does dynamically change but not on the BAR CHART because the BAR CHART is using testData.

This is the donut pie chart

```
d3.select("#manpowerChartPie svg") .datum([pieChartData]) .transition(500).call(chart); PjaxApp.onResize(chart.update);

pieFooter .append("div") .classed("controls", true) .selectAll("div") .data(pieChartData) //.data(testData) .enter().append("div") .classed("control", true) .style("border-top", function(d, i){ return "3px solid " + COLOR_VALUES[i]; })
.html(function(d) { return "<div class='key'>" + d.key + "</div>" + "<div class='value'>" + Math.floor(100 * d.y / sum) + " %</div>"; })
.on('click', function(d) { console.log('Footer -> '+d.key); pieChartUpdate.apply(this, [d]); barChart.update(); setTimeout(function() { barChart.update(); }, 100); });
```

Comment: I've cleaned up your question a bit. Unfortunately, it looks like you have uploaded the same image twice. Please [edit] your question and fix the link to your pie chart.

Comment: Thank you Chris for the update. I have already replaced the images and edit the wordings.